# Архитектура ПО. Rx .NET

Tags: c#, .net, архитектура

Всем привет! Недавно столкнулся с интересной задачей которая была решена "на коленке" и теперь ее нужно довести до ума. 
Суть такова. Нам по http приходят различные объекты. После получения, объекту необходимо пройти некоторое количество шагов валидации. После успешной валидации сообщение отправляется другому сервису. в зависимости от режима обработки, мы можем ждать или не ждать ответа от другого сервиса. Но результат валидации мы все равно отправляем обратно. Каждый валидатор, в текущем решении бросает exception в случае не прохождения валидации. Если все ок, передает сообщение следующему. Также объекты могут быть нескольких типов и в зависимости от типа, строятся различные комбинации валидаторов.

Вопросов два.

1. Как красиво генерировать цепочку валидаторов?
2. Ка это все завернуть в Rx .NET ? Суть такова, что незахедленный exception ломает Rx pipeline. А передавать кастомный объект с флагом результата предыдущей валидации по пайпу и в каждом валидаторе его проверять не хочеться.

И конечно все объекты обрабатываются асинхронно.

Я думаю, что с потоковой обработкой кто-то да сталкивался, и может быть поделиться опытом.

Comment: `Как красиво генерировать цепочку валидаторов?` - использовать композитный валидатор, который состоит из нескольких валидаторов. `Ка это все завернуть в RX .NET` - если вы затрудняетесь это сделать, то, скорее всего, это и делать то не нужно. Какую задачу вам решит заворачивание этого всего в Rx?

Comment: И, кстати, бросать исключение если валидатор не сработал - имхо, не очень идея. Гораздо информативнее, чтобы каждый валидатор возвращал `ValidationResult`, в котором уже должна быть информация, что не так с объектом. И на это есть минимум 2 причины - 1) Вы сможете прогнать несколько валидаторов и собрать больше ошибок в результате 2) Бросание исключения не будет частью *логики* вашего приложения. По поводу исключений и когда их надо\не надо юзать [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exception-throwing)

Comment: Особенно вот это *X DO NOT use exceptions for the normal flow of control, if possible.*.  Если нужны примеры, поглядите на [ValidationResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationresult(v=vs.110).aspx), ну или вот [пример из мира Eclipse](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.validation.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fwst%2Fvalidation%2FValidationResult.html)

Comment: @ tym32167 по поводу нужно ли использовать Rx в данном случае - возможно и нет, скорее всего. Это один из вариантов. Насчет исключений и согласен и нет. Во первых цепочку валидации нужно прерывать при первом не пройденном. В случае с `ValidationResult` его нужно проверять в каждом валидаторе и сообщение идет по всему пайпу в любом случае. Это уже не норм. Как минимум дублирование кода.  В случае бросания исключения идет прерывание цепочки, а по перформансу нас устраивает(на данный момент) К тому же так удобней строить логику обработки сообщений.

Comment: @ tym32167 Как вариант можно рассмотреть chain responsibility. в какой-нибудь кастомной форме. Аля передовать в него `Action` или `Func` и таким образом строить цепочку.

Comment: @ tym32167 насчет композитного валидатора, спасибо. Забыл за него). Вот пришла мысль объединить валидатор с цепочкой + убрать исключения. Большой вопрос - сложность. Насколько это будет супортбл.

Comment: Что то вы мудрите. Пишите код как можно более просто. Я это вижу как композитный валидатор, который принимает набор валидаторов. Во время валидации он просто в цикле вызывает валидаторы. Если очередной валидатор вернул ошибку — цикл прервать, ошибку вернуть вызывающему коду. Никакого дублирования кода, никаких исключений, никаких проблем с производительностью и очень гибкое решение, можно построить хоть дерево валидаторов

Comment: И причем все, что вам тут нужно, это интерфейс валидатора с 1 методом валидации, который возвращает результат валидации. Если вам надо разные типы валидировать, сделайте интерфейс обобщенным, получите еще и безопасность типов в придачу. Дальше пишете реализации валидаторов, комбинируете их как хотите и все